# How to remove data from Excel file in R

Tags: r, statistics, coding-style

I'm fairly new to R, and I have  to solve this question. Can anyone help me? I've also attached the `FlyingFoxMonitoring.csv`

Question: Some of the records (rows) in the data set are inconsistent, in that either the total species count does not equal the sum of the counts for the three species, or the variable `FlyingFoxesAbsent` does not match the total count being zero or not. Remove inconsistent records from the data set.

Link to the csv. : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4emDVHKabEBdm1IVWE5a3FkUU0/view?usp=sharing

Posting the code below will help so much. Been trying to solve the question, and I'm having major troubles.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far

Comment: You save some trouble (generally speaking) by using `data.table::fread("FlyingFoxMonitoring.csv")` to import the data

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it on import, but you can do it after you import the data.

```
require(dplyr)
df <- read.csv("FlyingFoxMonitoring.csv")
df.sub <- df %>%
          mutate(FF.sum = BlackFlyingFox.Count + GreyHeadedFlyingFox.Count + LittleRedFlyingFox.Count),
                 Keep.ind = ifelse(FF.sum == TotalSpeciesCount | (isTRUE(FlyingFoxesAbsent) & TotalSpeciesCount == 0 ), 1, 0)) %>%
          filter(Keep.ind == 1)
```

This code creates two new variables `FF.sum` which is the sum of the the various `___FlyinFox.Count` and `Keep.ind` which is an indicator that is generated to check to see if `FF.sum` and `TotalSpeciesCount` are equal and to see if both `FlyingFoxAbsent == TRUE` if `TotalSpeciesCount == 0`. If both conditions are true, then `Keep.ind = 1`, and if false `Keep.ind = 0`. Lastly this code will filter out all instances where this is false (i.e. `Keep.ind == 0`). Technically you don't need the indicator, but I keep it to verify and validate the data.